# C character array and its length

Tags: c, c-strings

I am studying now C with "C Programming Absolute Beginner's Guide" (3rd Edition) and there was written that all character arrays should have a size equal to the `string length + 1` (which is string-termination zero length). But this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    char name[4] = "Givi";
    printf("%s\n",name);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs `Givi` and not `Giv`. Array size is `4` and in that case it should output `Giv`, because 4 (string length) + 1 (string-termination zero character length) = 5, and the character array size is only `4`.

Why does my code output `Givi` and not `Giv`?

I am using MinGW 4.9.2 SEH for compilation.

Comment: Consider adding *-Wall -Wextra* to your compiler options, and fix any warnings you get. That should help avoiding many (but not all or even most!) mistakes like these.

Comment: @hyde: does not work: no warning, as that initializer perfectly conforms.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, of course it's valid C, and has valid use of initializing char arrays, but I'd have thought compiler would have detected suspicious use of known non-NUL-terminated char array here. Oh well, I guess it goes to demonstrate the part in the parenthesis of my previous comment...

Comment: This code is wrong. The fact that it happens to work is purely coincidence.

Comment: @hyde: I completely agree. There should be a warning at last with `-Wall`. Perhaps there is another option for that in gcc. Legacy crap (weras: the actual legacy crap is automitically adding NUL by the compiler).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker I would not call it "coincidence", because with the information given in the question, it will inevitably work on that environment. Only way to break it would be to link with some libraries which would have init handlers. I'd also say it is a deliberate design decision, that stack will be zeroed out at program start, not a coincidence. UB doesn't disallow the code working predictably and reliably in a given, well-defined environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are hitting what is considered to be [*undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). It's working now, but due to chance, not correctness.

In your case, it's because the memory in your program is probably all zeroed out at the beginning. So even though your string is not terminated properly, it just so happens that the memory right after it is zero, so `printf` knows when to stop.

```
+-----------------------+
|G|i|v|i|\0|\0|...      |
+-----------------------+
| your  | rest of       |
| stuff | memory (stack)|
+-----------------------+
```

Other languages, such as Java, have safeguards against this sort of situations. Languages like C, however, do less hand holding, which, on the one hand, allows more flexibility, but on the other, give you much, much more ways to shoot you in the foot with subtle issues such as this one. In other words, *if your code compiles, that doesn't mean it's correct and it won't blow up now, in 5 minutes or in 5 years*.

In real life, this is almost never the case, and your string might end up getting stored next to other things, which would always end up getting printed out together with your string. You never want this. Situations like this might lead to crashes, exploits and leaked confidential information.

See the following diagram for an example. Imagine you're working on a web server and the string "secret"--a user's password or key is stored right next to your harmless string:

```
+-----------------------+
|G|i|v|i|s|e|c|r|e|t    |
+-----------------------+
| your  | rest of       |
| stuff | memory (stack)|
+-----------------------+
```

Every time you would output what you would think is "Givi", you'd end up printing out the secret string, which is not what you want.

Comment: You could also explain what actually happens with that array initialization (just a suggestion).

Comment: Clarification: printf() outputs characters (one per byte) until it finds a binary zero. An array declaration does not add extra space for the zero or store the size of the array for use at run time. printf cannot know when to stop without the zeroed byte.

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
char name[4] = "Givi";
```

May give warning like:

```
string for array of chars is too long
```

Because the behavior is *Undefined*, still compiler may pass it. But if you debug, you will see:

```
name[0]                   'G'
name[1]                   'i'
name[2]                   'V'
name[3]                   '\0'
```

And so the output is

> Giv

Not **Give** as you mentioned in the question!

I'm using GCC compiler.

But if you write something like this:

```
char name[4] = "Giv";
```

Compiles fine! And output is

> Giv

Comment: The original also compiles fine.

Comment: Problem is not the initializer, that is well defined. problem is the printf. (Yes, I also would prefer at least a mandatory warning).

Comment: I updated my answer, and I run the following code,output is not same as OP mentioned, in GCC compiler!

Comment: Ehm... you apparrently compile as C++! Wrong language!

Comment: @Olaf, I build code in C, same! I give a try [here](http://ideone.com/fztc4P) too! Compiles fine but no output.

Comment: I just noticed the `.cpp` ending. Would be good to state the compiler, too. The screenshot is actually nonsense, as one can hardly read it. Just cite the dump of the array (copy/paste).

Comment: For me it compiles without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

What your book states is basically right, but there is missing the phrase "at least". The array can very well be larger.

You already stated the reason for the min length requirement. So what does that tell you about the example? It is **crap**!

What it exhibits is called **undefined behaviour** (UB) and might result in daemons flying out your nose for the `printf()` - not the initializer. It is just not covered by the C standard (well ,the standard actually says this is UB), so the compiler (and your libraries) are not expected to behave correctly.

For such cases, no terminator will be appended explicitly, so the string is not properly terminated when passed to `printf()".

Reason this does not produce an error is likely some legacy code which did exploit this to safe some bytes of memory. So, instead of reporting an error that the implicit trailing `'\0'` terminator does not fit, it simply does not append it. Silently truncating the string literal would also be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The byte after the last character always has to be 0, otherwise `printf` would not know when the string is terminanted and would try to access bytes (or `char`s) while they are not 0.

As Andrei said, apparently it just happened, that the compiler put at least one byte with the value 0 after your string data, so `printf` recognized the end of the string.

This can vary from compiler to compiler and thus is undefined behaviour.

There could, for instance, be a chance to have `printf` accessing an address, which your program is not allowed to. This would result in a crash.

Answer (score 1):

In C text strings are stored as zero terminated arrays of characters. This means that the end of a text string is indicated by a special character, a numeric value of zero (0), to indicate the end of the string.

So the array of text characters to be used to store a C text string must include an array element for each of the characters as well as an additional array element for the end of string.

All of the C text string functions (`strcpy()`, `strcmp()`, `strcat()`, etc.) all expect that the end of a text string is indicated by a value of zero. This includes the `printf()` family of functions that print or output text to the screen or to a file. Since these functions depend on seeing a zero value to terminate the string, one source of errors when using C text strings is copying too many characters due to a missing zero terminator or copying a long text string into a smaller buffer. This type of error is known as a buffer overflow error.

The C compiler will perform some types of adjustments for you automatically.  For instance:

```
char *pText = "four";   // pointer to a text string constant, compiler automatically adds zero to an additional array element for the constant "four"
char text[] = "four";   // compiler creates a array with 5 elements and puts the characters four in the first four array elements, a value of 0 in the fifth
char text[5] = "four";  // programmer creates array of 5 elements, compiler puts the characters four in the first four array elements, a value of 0 in the fifth
```

In the example you provided a good C compiler should issue at the minimum a warning and probably an error.  However it looks like your compiler is truncating the string to the array size and is not adding the additional zero string terminator. And you are getting lucky in that there is a zero value after the end of the string. I suppose there is also the possibility that the C compiler is adding an additional array element anyway but that would seem unlikely.